# Allow users to see who is voting to close their questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-close

After a question is closed, we know who voted to close it, but in the case of unsuccessful close attempts you never know who tried to close your question. This information should be made public.

If it turns out a small coterie is constantly trying to close a poster's questions - its not adding value to the board.

Comment: Close votes are not technically anonymous. When a question is closed, you can see which users voted to close it.

Comment: Why would u even bother when ur post is eventually not closed? And when it is closed u'll get to know the names of the close voters..

Answer (score 4):

This is a terrible idea.

Voting is anonymous by design; one significant reason for that is to prevent the poster from retaliating against the voter, be it by harassment or revenge-voting or whatever other means (it's easy to forget [Be Nice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) when somebody votes against you). By the tone of your post here, sectarian tensions are already an issue on this site, and giving frustrated users an actual *named target* they can vent their frustrations against is unlikely to improve matters *at all*. If anything, it'll just make things exponentially worse.

If your "small coterie" actually succeeds in closing a post, their names are already visible. If they *don't* succeed, well, that's the system working as intended. Either way, there's no real advantage to showing the names of voters early except to discourage anybody from voting at all, which basically breaks the whole system: [Maintaining question quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) is a fundamental part of the Stack Exchange model, and closing questions is an integral part of that.

If you're honestly worried about a voting ring, diamond moderators and community managers have the tools needed to suss that out and [handle it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) if necessary. Giving regular users the ability to point fingers just makes the site more hostile in general and creates drama for no good reason; flagging suspicious behaviour for moderator attention (or [contacting the Community Managers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/contact) directly if you don't trust your diamonds to handle it) allows them to handle the situation behind the scenes *without* ruining the site for everybody else.